# Mobilefirst 7.1 - Deploy Target problems on projects imported from 7.0

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, mobilefirst-server

I have a problem with some apps migrated from MF 7.0 to 7.1.

even though I set the (correct) server and Context path to "build the application to work with a different MobileFirst server" the resulting wlclient.properties file under Native\.shared folder is still reporting local machine in wlServerHost property (I am working on Windows Environment, targeting Windows Universal App).

Before migrating to 7.1 this procedure was OK, where I'm wrong?

Comment: Why are you looking at native\.shared? You need to look at native\assets\www\wlclient.properties - does this file reflect the updated configuration?

Comment: becouse after migrating I have not the path you have mentioned (and that I expected). Under Native now I have:

- buildtarget (folder)
- images (folder)
- <projectname>.Shared (folder)
- <projectname>.Windows8 (folder)
- <projectname>.WindowsPhone8 (folder)
- <projectname>.sln

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm getting this as well with IBM MobileFirst Platform Studio 7.1.0.00-20150907-1904.

As a local workaround you can edit the file post-build with the correct values. For me only the `wlServerHost` value does not change to the value I entered in the Build Settings and Deploy Target dialog.

I will open a defect for this; if you'd like to receive a fix you will need to open an IBM PMR (support ticket).

Comment: Will editing the wlServerHost in the post-build cause the authentictiy check to fail when authenticity protection is enabled?

Comment: Only if the other server you're pointing to does not have it configured (meaning the client is configured but the server is not).